# Java UnsupportedClassVersionError bad version number in .class file using ant task defination

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have a project build using jdk1.5 which is using ant as a build tool. As you know that in ant scripting we can write our own custom tasks like this and than later on we can use this.

```
<taskdef name="loadxml" classname="SomeClass" classpathref="CLASSPATH"/>
```

And here is the java class looks like.

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException;
import org.apache.tools.ant.Task;

class SomeClass extends Task
{
 .......................
}
```

The code works fine in windows server 2003 , but i am trying to run it on windows 7 64-bit.

I currently have my java home variable pointing to jdk 1.5. On my system i have java 8 installed.  The ant version (by ant -version) is coming as 1.7.1.

The ant script works perfect , but when it comes to that xml line mentioned above at top, it gives the following error.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file


   at   org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:508)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:397)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.Delegati

ngMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:758)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.start(Main.java:179)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.main(Main.java:268)

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:116)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:394)

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.defineClassFromData(AntClassLoader.java:1146)
at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.getClassFromStream(AntClassLoader.java:1324)
at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1388
)
at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1341)
at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1088)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:164)
```

I have tried changing the JDK to 64 bit and vice versa, tried installing different jres as well, tried different ant version as well. But some how i cant get to the bottom of it.

Can you please shed some light on it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've seen similar errors which result from _compiling_ class files with a higher version of java than the program is being _executed_ on.

Comment: yes you are right. but in this case, i cant seem to find what is compiled higher. I have manually checked the version of class using javap command and it is coming as 49 means java 5.

Answer (score 3):

> I currently have my java home variable pointing to jdk 1.5.

That is probably the problem.  It looks like you are trying to use a version of Ant that has been compiled for a newer Java platform.  Running it on an ancient copy of Java won't work.

You should UNINSTALL the JDK 1.5 installation.  It is years out of date.  You have a Java 8 (JDK I assume) install, so use that.

Then update your JAVA_HOME to point to the Java 8 install.

> I have tried changing the JDK to 64 bit and vice versa

That won't help.  It is not a 32 bit versus 64 bit problem.  The problem is that you are >>using<< an ancient JRE / JDK via your JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (Using Java 1.5 and Ant 1.7.1).  I upgraded to ant 1.9.7 and that resolved my problem.  Make sure you change the ANT_HOME, antrc locations.